# Does 'I'm ok.' mean yes or no?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand in the restaurant if the server asks whether you want ketchup or not? You answer `I'm good. Thanks.`. That means `no`. However, I heard when someone was asked `would you like ...?`, and they answered `I'm ok.`. And the first person took it as rejection. Now I'm confused. Does `I'm ok.` really mean `yes` or `no`?

Comment: Why should "I'm OK" not mean the same as "I'm good"? I'm confused by the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach did I say they are the same?

Comment: No, you implied they are different. I'm asking why you think they are different, when *OK* and *good* are synonymous (that is, both phrases indicate "No thanks" and that's how both waitresses interpreted them.)

Comment: No offending. According to you logic, `good job` should be the same as `ok job`?

Comment: That's a different usage, and "OK job" implies "adequate, sufficient for purpose" (which is similar to your question, I suppose: "I have sufficient, thank you") Your question should still include **why** you think "I'm OK" should not be the same as "I'm good", that is, **why** the second waitress got it wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think 95% of chance, if not all, as far as I'm aware of, people say `I'm good.`. However, I indeed heard someone said `I'm ok.`, it's kind of rare to me. The reason I was confused probably was because if they say `ok.` when being asked `would you like?`, I thought it would mean `yes.`. So `I'm ok.` and `ok.` seem to be completely different.

Comment: Yes, "I'm OK, thanks" ("I have sufficient") and "OK, thanks" ("Yes, more would be a good idea") are different. If that is your question, please [edit it](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/441477/edit) so that it can be answered (not just in comments, now that we have clarified what you are asking).

Comment: Both responses were in the negative and meant the same thing. If one person took it as a "rejection" and the other didn't, that's just a subjective reaction. But the responses mean the same thing: no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question seems to call for opinion, so here's mine:

To me it seems that *I'm ok / good / fine* indicates that *I have no need of anything at the moment*. So if I'm being offered something, it basically means, *No, thank you* -- which would be a more formal and polite expression to use. Some people might take that as "rejection", although I doubt that is the real intent. On the other hand, if people would use the more formal and polite expression, it might reduce the chances of misunderstandings.

PS: You might want to ask about this topic on Interpersonal Skills SE.